# Select last status for ticket number

Tags: sql

My table is:

[image]

I need to select all column by last status_changes. Result would be:

[image]

i tried this code:

```
with t_lastchanges as (
        SELECT
            issue_number,
            MAX (status_change_date) as lastchanges
        FROM
            table
        group by
            issue_number        
)

SELECT  DISTINCT  
    jvi.issue_number, jvi.current_status , t_lastchanges.lastchanges  
FROM
    table jvi
inner join t_lastchanges on
        jvi.status_change_date = t_lastchanges.lastchanges  and t_lastchanges.issue_number = jvi.issue_number 
ORDER BY 
    jvi.issue_number
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0):

In most SQL dialects, when using aggregates (like max), you need to use group by.

```
SELECT project,
       issue_number,
       creation_date,
       assignee_,
       current_status,
       max(status_change_date)
FROM table
GROUP BY project,
         issue_number,
         creation_date,
         assignee_,
         current_status
```

Should work.

Comment: it doesn't work, because some times column status_change_date can have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a window function to find the latest date per issue_number:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*
         dense_rank() over (partition by t.issue_number 
                            order by t.status_change_date desc) as rnk
  from the_table t
) as ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

Note that the result will include the `rnk` column. You will need to explicitly list all columns in the outer SELECT that you want, if you want to exclude that.

Comment: it doesn't work, because some time column status_change_date can have the same values and when i get the same rank for issue_number. Such as

issue_number   status_change_date rank
102                    01/03/2022 10:00     1
102                    01/03/2022 10:00     1


Sorry for that, it's my mistake that i don't tell about that

Comment: @Vlad: then use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`